# Define own alphabet and perform MultipleSequenceAlignment in biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, sequence-alignment

I want to do a MultipleSequenceAlignment in biopython but with a self defined Alphabet.
The Background is: My sequences are sequences of numeric states and there are up to 5000 states. Thus I need an alphabet with 5000 letters, e.g. '0001', '0042', '4999'. Those sequences are up to 50 states/letters long.

So my main questions are:

- How can I define such an Alphabet?
- How can I use this Alphabet with the MultipleSequenceAlignment?

Alternatively: Is it possible to perform a MultipleSequenceAlignment on Lists/Arrays instead of Sequences?

Thanks for you Time & Help!

Comment: try posting this to biostars.org

Comment: be very careful, many aligners take evolutionary history into account. E.g. transition/transversion ratio etc. Doing what you suggest will violate the assumptions behind these methods!

Answer (score 0):

You can define an Alphabet subclassing `Bio.Alphabet.Alphabet`. Maybe your case is similar to `ThreeLetterAlphabet`:

```
class ThreeLetterProtein(Alphabet): 
    """Three letter protein alphabet.""" 
    size = 3 
    letters = [ 
        "Ala", "Asx", "Cys", "Asp", "Glu", "Phe", "Gly", "His", "Ile",
        "Lys", "Leu", "Met", "Asn", "Pro", "Gln", "Arg", "Ser", "Thr",
        "Sec", "Val", "Trp", "Xaa", "Tyr", "Glx",
        ]
```

The second part of the question is confusing. If you want Biopython to do the alignment, AFAIK you cannot do it other than `Bio.pairwise2`. Biopython has only wrappers to popular alignment tools such as Muscle, Clustal, TCoffee... Then it can read the outputs as `MultipleSeqAlignment` with `Bio.AlignIO`.

Comment: I managed to define the Alphabet, but `Bio.pairwise2` ignores the size parameter. This is also the case for the `ThreeLetterProtein()`,
```
tla = Alphabet.ThreeLetterProtein()
tls1 = SeqRecord(Seq("AlaAlaPheAlaAla", tla))
tls2 = SeqRecord(Seq("AlaAlaProAlaAla", tla))
align = pairwise2.align.globalxx(tls1,tls2)
```
Results in `AlaAlaP-heAlaAla` and `AlaAlaPro-AlaAla`.

Comment: `Bio.pairwise2` won't align any sequences other than single letter sequences. What I said is that Biopython doesn't "align" except with that particular module. Maybe you should try some "word alignment" algorithm outside Biopython.